# Design pattern for object creation

Tags: java, design-patterns

have to create an abstract class, say Part. But there are two type of parts,

Part1: This part has 3 instance variables, inside,outside,middle

Part2: This part has 2 instance variables, top, bottom

Finally, both Part are extending an abstract class Part, so finally, in Java its like this

```
abstract Class Object{
   public abstract String toString();
}

abstract class Part{
    abstract void print();
}

Class Part1 extends Part1{
    List <Object> inside = new ArrayList <Object> ();
    List <Object> outside = new ArrayList <Object> ();
    List <Object> medium = new ArrayList <Object> ();
    void print(){
        //go through all the list and print the object
    }
}

Class Part1 extends Part2{
    List <Object> top = new ArrayList <object> ();
    List <Object> bottom = new ArrayList <object> ();
    void print(){
        //go through all the list and print the object
    }
}
```

my issue is which design pattern can I apply for the creation of Part, I'm still a newbie in pattern, for me its builder because I have to come up with the same type of Object having different representation. But the object is not complex !!

Comment: I'm not sure this question is answerable when it's this vague. You have to consider *why* you need to abstract `Part` creation. I.e. how will whichever design pattern you should use be applied in the rest of the codebase? Otherwise they're all as valid as the others. (That is, all equally useless.)

Comment: The class using the object Part doesn't care its instance variable but only its print methods, so, in that class, I think we should abstract it creation and only give the client a part object on which it can invoke the print method, am i right??

Comment: Yes, but that's true for any objects with a shared interface at the point where they're used, and it doesn't matter if they were created using a factory or a builder or by a constructor call. I was asking for some input on how the code where these objects will be created / managed, because that's what's relevant to deciding how to abstract their creation.

Answer (score 0):

See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Code/Design_Patterns#Creational_Patterns.

I prefere factory pattern usage or prototype:

Prototype example:

```
Class PartsFactory
{
    Part createPart(string partType)
    {
        if (partType.equals("Type1")) return new Part1();
        if (partType.equals("Type2")) return new Part2();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Factory example:

```
interface PartsFactory
{
    Part createPart();
}

Class Parts1Factory implements PartsFactory
{
    Part createPart()
    {
        return new Part1();
    }
}

Class Parts2Factory implements PartsFactory
{
    Part createPart()
    {
        return new Part2();
    }
}
```

Comment: for the factory example, the create method takes different parameters, sometimes inside,outside,medium or sometimes top,bottom